# Setting a listview in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I know this has been asked before, but i honestly am not getting enough from others questions. Thank you for your time in reading this. I cant get the compiled view to show the data in the list view, and Im not sure what im doing wrong. Im using java Scene Builder, and have this class set as the controller. Can provide more info if/when needed

```
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

    public class DeanClassDbShowController {
    //To hold the output, then the second one just in case
    String test ="";
    String combiner ="";
    @FXML private ListView<String> dbList;
    private final ObservableList<String> courses = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initialize() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost", 27017 );
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("prog3");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Courses");
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
        {
            while(cursor.hasNext())
            {
                Document oldDoc = cursor.next();
                test = oldDoc.getString("courseName");
                combiner=  ("Class: "+ test);
                test = oldDoc.getString("courseNumber");
                combiner+= ("  Class Number: "+test);
                test = oldDoc.getString("instructor");
                combiner+= ("  Instructor: "+ test);
                test = oldDoc.getInteger("students").toString();
                combiner+= ("  Students: "+ test);
                courses.add(combiner);
                //dbList.getItems().add(combiner);          
            }
            dbList.setItems(courses);
            //dbList = new ListView(courses);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The listview is showing the data going in correctly, it just isnt displaying after its there.

Comment: Why use fields for the `String` variables? You do not seem to use them except for assembling hte strings in the `initialize` methods. For this purpose local variables would be sufficient. Furthermore introducing a new scope around the `while` loop and the following statement seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had some scene viewer settings wrong.  Had to change my fixed cell size and opacity, I for some reason put it at zero.